# Ignore duplicate rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm using **python** and **psycopg2** to insert a dict to my **PostgreSQL** database.

I have postgres version 13.2

At the moment I only have the code below to execute :

```
 INSERT INTO movie_data(title, description, rating, published, cast_and_crew, age_group, country)
 VALUES ('movie name', 'something', 8, 2020, 'an actor', 'pg-13', 'GB')
```

But because I already have this row in my db I get the **'already exists'** error.

I've tried the *ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING* but I get the error below :

```
there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

What's the best way to ignore the duplicate rows and keep on inserting?

I'm new to **SQL** so if anyone could explain and include the whole code for this purpose I would really appreciate it.

UPDATE : below is my `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE public.movie_data
(
    title text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    published integer,
    cast_and_crew text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    age_group text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    country text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    rating integer,
    CONSTRAINT movie_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (title, description)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.movie_data
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` statement with all constraints. Don't you have a primary key?

Comment: I already have the table, I only want to insert the data into it.

Comment: I've also set primary key on title and description only

Comment: What is is your complete `INSERT` statement with `ON CONFLICT` clause? Update your question with this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

error is clear , you need to have a unique constraint on your table for the columns that needs to be unique

```
alter table movie_data
add constraint constraintname unique (title, description);
```

now you can use this constraint :

```
 INSERT INTO movie_data(title, description, rating, published, cast_and_crew, age_group, country)
 VALUES ('movie name', 'something', 8, 2020, 'an actor', 'pg-13', 'GB')
 on conflict on constraint constraintname do nothing;
```

as Adrian pointed out , instead of that , if your Primary key  is on those column that needs to be unique , you simply could :

```
 INSERT INTO movie_data(title, description, rating, published, cast_and_crew, age_group, country)
 VALUES ('movie name', 'something', 8, 2020, 'an actor', 'pg-13', 'GB')
 on conflict (title, description) do nothing;
```

Comment: Since you already have  a `PRIMARY KEY` on (title, description) you could skip this and just do  `ON CONFLICT (title, description) DO NOTHING`.

Comment: @eshirvana Thanks a lot man, it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to have a primary key with duplicated rows? The main purpose of primary keys is to uniqueliy identify rows.

I think you should drop your primary key:

```
alter table public.movie_data drop constraint movie_data_pkey;
```

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what @AryanHab is trying to achieve. That is to not have duplicate rows by using `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` to skip the `INSERT` of any row that duplicates an existing row. This is more commonly known as an `UPSERT`, though that more accurately describes the other option:  `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`. Dropping the PK is not the answer.

Comment: I don't think that is what he meant. "Keep on inserting" he wrote, that doesn't mean UPDATE.

Comment: The whole quote is: "What's the best way to ignore the duplicate rows and keep on inserting?" So @AryanHab is choosing to ignore any `INSERT` that is a duplicate row by using `DO NOTHING` and then proceeding with `INSERT`s that are not duplicate rows. That is why it is not a true `UPSERT` as I mentioned.

Comment: Well, `UPSERT` is the most accurate reasoning.